# How do I extract parts of a video with a specific aspect ratio with ffmpeg or mencoder?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, extract, mencoder, aspect-ratio

I've got some recordings from TV. The movies are all in 4:3 but the advertisement is in 16:9. My input format is a mpeg 2 transport stream. I would like to convert my movies to mp4 with h264 video and aac audio but delete all frames from the video with 16:9 aspect ratio. The sound should also be deleted at the matching frames.
Converting mts to mp4 is easy with ffmpeg but how do I extract the frames with 4:3 aspect ratio?

converting mts to mp4:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mts -b:v 6000k -b:a 256k -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -o output.mp4
```

I'm under a gentoo linux with ffmpeg version 0.10.3 and MEncoder 1.1-4.5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Comskip](http://www.kaashoek.com/comskip/) is a software that can detect ads based on a variety of characteristics. One of them is "changes in aspect ratio". So you should integrate comskip into your process.

Comment: I'm under linux only :(
I resolved this with ProjectX. It's a java tool that has a gui and a commandline interface. I wrote a simple bash script that invokes ProjectX with several parameters for all my movies. Works great :D